# how to emit the data from child to parent without calling an event(vue 2)

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I need to send the data from the child component to its parent(by emitting), once the child is loaded without calling any event like click or keyUp,...

in other words, I want once the child component is mounted, it automatically sends some of its data to the parent and not necessarily calling an event to emit the data.

is there any way to do that in vue.js?

I'll thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read about how `props` work: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

One thing you could try to do is pass an Object as a prop, and mutate that object inside the child, than monitor object changes in the parent. But to be honest that conflicts with the ideas of how Vue works, and is based practice. So don't do it.

But what is the problem really? Emitting a custom event is by far the easiest thing to do, and fully in line with Vue.

In parent:

```js
<my-comp @initiated="handleInitiated"/>
```

In child, after you did the initial work:

```js
this.$emit('initiated', initiationData)
```

If you are worried about event propagation when using default event names, this solution with a custom event name solves that. Of course you can also always stop further propagation once you caught it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `$emit` i suggest using some `store` (state management).

It could be global store or sub store. A thing that will make it easier to watch changes in any parent/child components.

Imagine that you want to listen inside a very deep child component from a parent one. Would you start passing around events ?

The flow is :

1- Update the store from deep nested child

2- use a store getter in your parent component to watch/compute changes

Checkout **vuex** https://vuex.vuejs.org/